# Xpath validation fails on automated test with maven / soap-ui plugin

Tags: web-services, maven, automated-tests, soapui

We are using Soap-UI for writing some web-services tests.

I put this XPath validation in one of them:

```
count(//mynode) > 1
```

This is working fine while executing from SOAP-UI software, but when the continuous integration (jenkins) execute it through the Maven Soap-UI plugin, I receive this error:

```
[XPath Match] junit/framework/ComparisonFailure
```

I guess there is a missing library somewhere but cannot figure what to do.

What is strange is that I do not refers any jUnit tests as I just call URL's of web-services.

Comment: Can you post the full error? You can also run Maven with the `-e` or `-X` parameters for more log/debug information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found that there is a junit dependency to add with the help of [this thread](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/soapUI-Maven-Plugin-and-mySQL/m-p/22683#M10354)

Here is the dependency I had to add in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For the maven-soapui-plugin.

The whole config will looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>services-customer</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>services/customer/smoke-tests.xml</projectFile>
                <projectProperties>
                    <value>IdmpDataEndPointHost=${smoke.dataload.url}</value>
                    <value>WebServiceEndPointHost=http://${smoke.tomcat.server}:${smoke.tomcat.port}</value>
                </projectProperties>
                <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/soapui-results/services/customer</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```